# Disappearing Object in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

For some reason, when I translate my object around the window, it disappears. Here is an image to show what I am talking about. Can you see why this would be happening? Thanks.

http://img215.imageshack.us/img215/160/disappearingbunny.png

Comment: How do you set up your projection matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a [clipping plane](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Clipping) issue.